# AutoLayout to adjust image size proportional to 50%

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, storyboard

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12840332/1563878) and I have tried with many examples but i could not put two images one beside the other, each one with a width 50% and at the same time that this images maintain their aspect ratio. I do not understand what restrictions need to.

I have this:

[image]

In the image you can see the  viewcontroller structure, 2 imageview and the constraints.

Please I need help, at least one similar example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you have missing constraints on your scene, so that could be an issue.

I would put the `UIImageView`s in a container view pinned to your main view, making sure there are no missing constraints. The benefit of this is in debugging - you can give it a different BG colour and make sure it's resizing itself properly on the simulator/device. I found that putting the image views inside this helps enormously.

Then you need to specify Aspect Ratio constraints on your image views, and also make them equal widths and heights. Add some small constant horizontal spacing between your image views and top/leading/trailing to the container view, and let auto-layout decide the optimal image sizes.

I've included a screenshot of my storyboard:-

[image]

This renders like so:-

[image]